# SWAP Selected Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to swap the selected rows as a quick way for users to selected the opposite to what they have already selected.

For example:

**Current Selection:**

```
ID    SelectedUID
------------------
1         
2         
3         CJ
4         
5
```

**SWAP Selection:** (this is what I am trying to achieve)

```
ID    SelectedUID
------------------
1         CJ
2         CJ
3         
4         CJ
5         CJ
```

Is there a function or an easy way to do this in SQL Server?

**EDIT**

Would this be an appropriate Stored Procedure? I am receiving an error when I execute this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcSWAPSelections]
@FROMCLAUSE AS VARCHAR(8000),
@UPDATETABLE AS VARCHAR(50),
@GUID AS VARCHAR(3),
@WHERECLAUSE AS VARCHAR(8000)

AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + @UPDATETABLE + '
             SET Selected' + @GUID + '.UID = CASE WHEN Selected' + @GUID + '.UID = @GUID
                                                 THEN NULL
                                                 ELSE @GUID
                                            END
             ' +  @FROMCLAUSE + '
             ' + @WHERECLAUSE + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@FROMCLAUSE VARCHAR(8000), @UPDATETABLE VARCHAR(50), @GUID VARCHAR(3), @WHERECLAUSE VARCHAR(8000)', @FROMCLAUSE,@UPDATETABLE, @GUID, @WHERECLAUSE; 

END
```

Comment: WOW. That new stored procedure you posted is SCARY!!! You should look up sql injection. This procedure is wide open. I am curious why you have a variable named GUID that is in fact a varchar 3. ;)

Comment: What I pass through to the SP is very controlled as in users cant affect it since it is all "hard-coded" in the front-end. Also some users have char(3) and some char(2) ;) - let me know if you can help me verify this scary SP :P

Comment: No offense but that does not protect you. What is the front end? A website using request.form? Even so, the procedure itself is vulnerable. The reason it isn't working is because all your parameters are NULL because you didn't assign them values. Change your exec line to this and it should work (I had to add spaces after the @ due to limitations here). EXEC sp_executesql @ sql, N'@ FROMCLAUSE VARCHAR(8000), @ UPDATETABLE VARCHAR(50), @ GUID VARCHAR(3), @ WHERECLAUSE VARCHAR(8000)'
, @ FROMCLAUSE = @ FROMCLAUSE, @ UPDATETABLE = @ UPDATETABLE, @ GUID = @ GUID, @ WHERECLAUSE = @ WHERECLAUSE;

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to have a third table

```
Selections
ID Selection
1  NULL
2  CJ
```

Then in the swap table link to it, then you only need to switch in the selections table. Same number of operations, but only two records updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with 2 updates.

```
Update YourTable Set SelectedUID = 'SomeValueThatDoesntExist'
where SelectedID = 'CJ'

Update YourTable Set SelectedUID = 'CJ'
where SelectedID = 'SomeValueThatDoesntExist'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only 2 different values in the table in *one* update, which means you don't need a transaction to span multiple UPDATEs

```
UPDATE
   SomeTable
SET
   SelectedUID = CASE WHEN SelectedUID <> 'CJ' THEN 'CJ' ELSE '' END
```

or...

```
   SelectedUID = CASE WHEN SelectedUID = 'CJ' THEN '' ELSE 'CJ' END
```

or...

```
   SelectedUID = CASE WHEN SelectedUID = 'CJ' THEN NULL ELSE 'CJ' END
```

Answer (score -1):

This function should help.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_SwapValues
(
@InputStr VARCHAR(5),
@ReplaceStr1 VARCHAR(5),
@ReplaceStr2 VARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Return VARCHAR(5)
    SELECT @Return = CASE
                 WHEN @InputStr = @ReplaceStr1 THEN @ReplaceStr2
                 WHEN @InputStr = @ReplaceStr2 THEN @ReplaceStr1
                 ELSE @InputStr
                 END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Return

END
GO
```

**USAGE:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT,
                  SelectedUID VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES  (1, ''),
       (2, ''),
       (3, 'CJ'),
       (4, ''),
       (5, '')

SELECT ID,SelectedUID
FROM @table

--USAGE WITH SELECT

SELECT ID,
      dbo.udf_SwapValues(SelectedUID, 'CJ', '')
FROM @table

--USAGE WITH UPDATE
UPDATE t
SET t.SelectedUID = dbo.udf_SwapValues(t.SelectedUID, 'CJ', '')
FROM @table t

SELECT *
FROM @table
```

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to create a scalar function instead of just 2 update statements. Scalar functions are notoriously poor for performance.

Comment: @SeanLange, The op asked for "Is there a function or an easy way to do this in SQL Server?". However yes I agree UDF's when improperly used can cause a huge performance bottleneck. However seeing the question, "a quick way for users to selected the opposite" tell me that the list in question can not be too big so performance may not even come into the equation.

Comment: But why resort to a methodology that is slow when a fast one is the simple way? The biggest issue with scalar functions is the mentality that it is ok on a small result set. This leads people to see it used in one place and use the same thing elsewhere where the performance will crush your server. The point I am making is that it is never acceptable to say "well in this case performance won't be an issue". Make ALL your code fast and you don't have to worry about it.